# Meaning of "mögen" as "dürfen"

Tags: meaning, modal-verb

From Der Spiegel:

> Mindestens so gefährlich wie der gesellschaftliche Reformeifer des Kreml-Chefs ist für die DDR ausgangs der Achtzigerjahre Gorbatschows Aufforderung, die Ostblockstaaten **mögen** ihre internen Angelegenheiten nun eigenständig regeln. Der große Bruder greife künftig nicht mehr ein.

It seems that "mögen" here is used in the meaning of "dürfen", i.e., the countries in the Eastern bloc "are allowed to" take care of their internal matters. However, as I checked [here](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/mogen), "mögen" doesn't really have that meaning. In [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/moegen) the closest one is

> zum Ausdruck der [Auf]forderung o. Ä.; sollen

Is my interpretation of "mögen" here correct? If so, is this considered rare usage, or "gehoben"? (In other words, would you use this in everyday conversation?)

Comment: Take a look at meaning 3-f at the first page you link, it gives an example as well: "du möchtest dich brieflich melden - you should write". Another somewhat common idiom is "etwas gefälligst tun mögen", as in ["Kapitalanleger erhalten einen Anruf mit dem Hinweis, sie mögen gefälligst ihre Steuerehrlichkeit nachweisen.](http://www.rechtsanwalt-widmaier.de/aktuell_detail.php?id=41)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, the *Konjunktiv I* of *mögen* is used to indicate an optative sentence (German: *Wunschsatz*):

*Mögest du in interessanten Zeiten leben.* (May you live in interesting times.)

Comment: Ich möchte noch hinzufügen, dass das "mögen" gerne verwendet wird, um Aufforderungen jeglicher Art in der indirekten Rede wiederzugeben. Gorbatschow hat natürlich nie gesagt: "Von nun an **möget** ihr euch um euren eigenen Kram kümmern". Hier wird ein komplexer Sachverhalt komprimiert wiedergegeben.

Answer (score 5):

It's more like *sollen*, actually, in the sense of being supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

In älterer Sprache kann ein hoher Herr einem Bediensten, den er noch mit "Er" anredet, sagen: Er mag jetzt gehen. Sinn: Der Bedienstete darf sich aus dem Zimmer des Herrn entfernen, der Herr hat nichts dagegen. Verallgemeinernd kann man sagen, dieses "mögen" hat den Sinn "die Erlaubnis geben". Dieser Gebrauch ist heute wohl selten.

Übrigens ist "mögen" im Spiegel-Zitat keine Konjunktiv-Form, sondern Indikativ sie mögen. Wäre im Zitat die Rede vom DDR-Staat, würde der Satz lauten: Der DDR-Staat mag nun seine internen Angelegenheiten selbst regeln. Bei "sie mögen" ist Indikativ und Konjunktiv formgleich.

PS  Ich sehe, mit dem Modus von "mögen" habe ich mich vertan. Ich habe den folgenden Konjunktiv "greife" nicht richtig beachtet. Schaut nach Wiedergabe in indirekter Rede aus.

Comment: Wenn die beiden formgleich sind, wie gelangst Du dann zu dem Schluss, es handle sich um den Indikativ?

Comment: Gorbatschow äußert keinen Wunsch, sondern gibt eine Erlaubnis.

Comment: Der Argumentation bzgl. des Indikativs liegt wohl die Annahme zugrunde, dass in der Wendung `X [mögen] Y selbst tun.` der Modus des Verbes `mögen` unabhängig von dessen Numerus und insbesonders identisch für alle unter sonst gleichen Gegebenheiten ist. Dazu wäre aber zu erklären, wieso der Satz nicht `Der DDR-Staat möge nun seine...` lauten könne.

Comment: Verstehe nichts. Der Indikativ ist: mag mast mag mögen mögt mögen. Der Konjunktiv: möge mögest möge mögen möget mögen.Also sind Form 4 und 6 formgleich.

Comment: Ich sage nicht, ob ich der Argumentation zustimme, aber sie lautet: Wenn die beiden Sätze "Die Ostblockstaaten mögen ihre internen Angelegenheiten nun eigenständig regeln." und "Der Ostblockstaaten mag ihre internen Angelegenheiten nun eigenständig regeln." bis auf die Einzahl/Mehrzahl dasselbe bedeuten, dann müsse das Verb in beiden Sätzen wohl auch im selben Modus (Indikativ und Konjunktiv) stehen. Oder anderes Beispiel: "Und tatsächlich: Die Jungen stehen eindeutig gerade da." klingt in der Einzahl mit dem Konjunktiv merkwürdig: "Und tatsächlich: Der Junge stehe eindeutig gerade da."

Comment: Oder zusammengefasst: Die Argumentation lautet, dass nicht beide Interpretationen (Konjunktiv oder Indikativ) möglich seien nur weil sie formgleich sind. Der Beispielssatz zeige, dass eine Interpretation der anderen vorzuziehen sei.

Comment: Es ist der Konjunktiv, denn es wird in indirekter Rede Gorbatschows Auffroderung wiedergegeben. Mit dem Singular "DDR-Staat" müßte es heißen: "gefährlich ... ist für die DDR ... Gorbatschows Aufforderung, der DDR-Staat möge seine internen Angelegenheiten nun eigenständig regeln"

Comment: Man beachte auch den Konjunktiv im folgenden Satz.

Comment: Ich sehe, dass die Einwände gegen meine Deutung als Indikativ berechtigt sind. Habe das in meinem Post angemerkt.