# Bedeutung von "mögen" in "mögen die Hürden auch noch so hoch sein"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, modal-verb

Aus [Angela Merkels Rede am 9. November](http://www.bundesregierung.de/Content/DE/Rede/2014/11/2014-11-09-merkel-gedenkstaette-berliner-mauer.html):

> Träume können wahr werden. Nichts muss so bleiben, wie es ist – **mögen die Hürden auch noch so hoch sein**. Diese Erfahrung wollen wir mit unseren Partnern in der Welt teilen.

Es erinnert mich an den Satz

> [Mögest du in interessanten Zeiten leben.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/16099/meaning-of-m%C3%B6gen-as-d%C3%BCrfen)

Da drückt **mögen** einen Wunsch aus, dass der Zuhörer in interessanten Zeiten lebt. In Merkels Rede ist es hingegen klar, sie wünscht nicht, dass die Hürden noch so hoch sind. Was bedeutet dann **mögen** hier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In diesem Fall könnte man den Satz (mit der unten beschriebenen Änderung) so umformulieren:

> mögen die Hürden auch noch so hoch sein == auch wenn die Hürden noch so hoch sind

Diese beiden Versionen unterscheiden sich höchstens in der Unsicherheit darüber, wie hoch die Hürden wirklich sein werden (wenn überhaupt). Der Ersatz-Ausdruck klingt etwas realistischer und auf Erfahrungen basierend als das Original, wohingegen im Original die Wahrscheinlichkeit für hohe Hürden ziemlich hoch ist. Eventuell könnte man es auch so sagen:

> auch wenn die Hürden *möglicherweise* sehr hoch sind

"Mögen" drückt in dieser Bedeutung also aus, dass es so sein *könnte*, aber nicht unbedingt so ist. Es wird sehr oft benutzt, um die Irrelevanz einer Tatsache, über die man keine/wenig Kenntnis hat, auszudrücken. Klassisches Beispiel: Jemand erklärt einem, dass das, was man vorhat, auf keinen Fall funktionieren kann und führt als Begründung Tatsache X an. Man antwortet:

> Das (X) mag ja so sein, aber auch dafür hätte ich eine Lösung.

Dies drückt aus, dass ich zwar nicht genau weiß, ob X zutrifft, aber selbst "wenn es tatsächlich so wäre (wie Du sagst), hätte ich dafür eine Lösung". Die Tatsache, dass der zweite Teil des Satzes (wie bei dem "wenn"-Satz) im Konjunktiv steht, zeigt, dass "mögen" in diesem Fall eine ähnliche Unsicherheit ausdrückt.

Bei dem Zitat in der Frage stammt die Unsicherheit allerdings daher, dass man noch nicht weiß, wie hoch die Hürden sein werden, da diese von Fall zu Fall verschieden hoch sein können (je nachdem, welcher Traum wahr werden soll, welche Dinge man verändern will). Das Prinzip ist aber das gleiche wie bei meinem Beispiel, bei dem die Unsicherheit einfach daher stammt, dass ich nicht weiß, ob Tatsache X wahr ist oder nicht.

---

Spekulativer Teil:
Ich bin kein Regelexperte, aber rein gefühlsmäßig ist diese Bedeutung von "mögen" gar nicht so weit von "wünschen" entfernt. Wenn man die Hürden als eigenständig denkende Wesen interpretiert, dann können sie sich noch so sehr wünschen "hoch zu sein", wir werden sie trotzdem überwinden (unabhängig davon, ob ihr Wunsch in Erfüllung geht). Genauso mit der Tatsache X oben, die "wollen kann", wahr zu sein, so viel sie will, aber in jedem Fall hätte ich eine Lösung.

EDIT: Mir ist gerade aufgefallen, dass das Wörtchen "möglich" auch daher kommt: Es kann so sein, ist aber nicht sicher. Die Umformulierung mit "möglicherweise" oben ist also gar nicht so anders als das Original. ;)

Answer (score 4):

„mögen“ kann in der Mehrzahl sowohl Indikativ Präsens als auch Konjunktiv Präsens darstellen. Die Bedeutung von „mögen“ unterscheidet sich, je nach Modus aber deutlich. Ist man sich unsicher, ersetzt man den Plural durch einen Singular:

1. Träume können wahr werden. Nichts muss so bleiben, wie es ist – **möge** die **Hürde** auch noch so hoch sein. Diese Erfahrung wollen wir mit unseren Partnern in der Welt teilen.
2. Träume können wahr werden. Nichts muss so bleiben, wie es ist – **mag** die **Hürde** auch noch so hoch sein. Diese Erfahrung wollen wir mit unseren Partnern in der Welt teilen.

Da (1) keinen Sinn ergibt - Deutung von möge als Optativ - ist (2) anzunehmen.

Answer (score 0):

Dieser Gebrauch von mögen ist einschränkend/konzessiv. Meistens in der Form "mag/mögen ... auch noch so +Adjektiv". Hier liegt immer ein Gegensatz zu Grunde: 
Träume können wahr werden. Es kann manchmal schwierig sein, trotzdem können Träume wahr werden.